# How to remove Python from System32?

Tags: windows-7, python

For some reason there is an unrecorded installation of Python on my System32 folder. I can say that that is the case because I can see these files on my System32 folder.

[image]

The problem is, I'm not sure if these are the only Python-related files scattered on my System32. I want to install a fresh copy of Python 2.7 but I want to get rid of these first. I don't see any installation records either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure if these are the only Python-related files scattered on my System32.

You can find other related files by sorting the date/time column.